# How to run mvn jqassistant:report via pom.xml?

Tags: report, pom.xml, jqassistant

I am trying to configure `jqassistant-maven-plugin` version 2.0.7 in my `pom.xml`.
Specifically, I want to create the report generated by the command `mvn jqassistant:report`.
I thought I could simply add a goal, like so:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
  <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.7</version>
  <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>default</id>
       <goals>
          <goal>scan</goal>
          <goal>analyze</goal>
          <goal>report</goal> <!-- doesn't generate a report -->
       </goals>
     </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

To clarify, I am looking to have the `site` folder generated. It is only there because I executed the command manually.

[image: File structure]

I also have a config file `jqassistant.yml` located in `.jqassistant` at top-level.
Any idea what I have to do, I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

As a side question, before upgrading the `pom.xml` also had the following config which I don't know how to migrate, if necessary at all:

```xml
<configuration>
  <xmlReportFile>${project.build.directory}/jqassistant/report.xml</xmlReportFile>
</configuration>
```

As mentioned, to trigger the report-generation I simply tried adding the `<goal>report<goal>`.
For the `xmlReportFile` I tried adding in the yml-config with no success like outlined in the comments:

```yaml
jqassistant:
  plugins:
    - group-id: org.jqassistant.contrib.plugin
      artifact-id: jqassistant-java-ddd-plugin
      version: 1.8.1
  analyze:
    groups:
      - java-ddd:Default
      - java-ddd:Strict
    report:
      fail-on-severity:
        - MAJOR
#      xml-report-file:
#        - ${project.build.directory}/jqassistant/jqassistant-report.xml
#      properties:
#        xml-report-file:
#          - ${project.build.directory}/jqassistant/jqassistant-report.xml
#  report:
#    xml-report-file:
#      - ${project.build.directory}/jqassistant/jqassistant-report.xml
#    properties:
#      xml-report-file:
#        - ${project.build.directory}/jqassistant/jqassistant-report.xml
```

Comment: Which mvn command are you executing on the command line?

Comment: @DirkMahler the command is `mvn jqassistant:report`

Comment: This should work if scan/analyze have been executed before. But it doesn't work if you just run "mvn clean verify", correct?

Answer (score 0):

The jqassistant:report goal by default is bound to the lifecycle phase site. So if you want to have this goal executed for "mvn install" then you'll need to specify a separate execution for it with a lifecycle phase "verify" or "install".

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. I did as you said but the "site" folder is still not generated.